# jq - insert values into subkey

Tags: json, jq

I have a httpie session file that looks like this:

```
{
   "headers": {
      "Host": "34.213.0.202",
      "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8",
      "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:67.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/67.0",
      "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5",
      "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate",
      "DNT": "1",
      "Connection": "keep-alive",
      "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1",
      "Cache-Control": "max-age=0"
    }
}
```

I would like to insert an item into headers (think *'.headers + {"Cookie": "xyz"}'*) but I would like the output to be the whole JSON. Using jq '.headers + {"Cookie": "xyz"}' only prints out the .headers value. What I am looking to get is the whole entire JSON, but with the cookie subkey included.

What's the way to get that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use assignment operators:

```
.headers += { Cookie: "xyz" }
```

```
.headers.Cookie = "xyz"
```

The latter one changes a bit when there are multiple fields to be added:

```
.headers |= (.Cookies = "xyz" | .Referer = "xyz")
```

Comment: @Saichovsky welcome. Consider marking this as accepted answer if it answers your question correctly.

Comment: I have. I had to wait for 8 minutes to accept it as I had just asked it. 

Another question would be how to add two subkeys. I want to add Cookie and Referer